# ServiceStack AuthProvider PreAuthenticate infinite loop

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I'm attempting to write a simple custom AuthProvider for authentication by API key on the URL.  I have based my code on the [BasicAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v4.0.40/src/ServiceStack/Auth/BasicAuthProvider.cs).

I am finding, however, that running the code from the BasicAuthProvider, before I make any changes at all, the **PreAuthenticate()** method gets recursively called each time the **authService.Post()** method is called:

```
    public void PreAuthenticate(IRequest req, IResponse res)
    {
        SessionFeature.AddSessionIdToRequestFilter(req, res, null); 

        var userPass = req.GetBasicAuthUserAndPassword();
        if (userPass != null)
        {
            var authService = req.TryResolve<AuthenticateService>();
            authService.Request = req;

            //** Post calls PreAuthenticate again **//

            var response = authService.Post(new Authenticate
            {
                provider = Name,
                UserName = userPass.Value.Key,
                Password = userPass.Value.Value
            });
        }
    }
```

Could anyone shed any light on why this might be?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the built-in `BasicAuthProvider` go into an infinite loop? What's different about your version?

Comment: No the built-in one works fine, that’s why I’m so confused. I Changed only its class name (AnotherBasicAuthProvider). It’s in the same namespace as the built-in one. I swapped the built-in one for the new one in AppHost config.

Comment: Can't think of why that would be then, can you update your question with your complete `AuthFeature` registration?

Comment: @mythz It turns out I had a mismatch in ServiceStack versions between two referenced projects (4.0.40 and 4.5.8).  Once I fixed that it worked.  Very sorry to have dragged StackOverflow into it - thanks!